# Can a Chromebook run Mac OS

Tags: macos, chromebook

I am thinking of getting a HP chrome book 11 or 14 (not sure yet) and I like Mac OSX could I run it on a chrome book? I also am curious if it could run Mine craft with shaders mod

Answer (score 1):

In short, no. Mac uses i386 and x86_64 processors. But it doesn't support ARM processors, which is what chromebook uses.

Comment: While your answer is for the common user entirely correct, it is worth noting [this](http://mobile.osnews.com/story.php/25588/No_Mac_OS_X_wasn_t_ported_to_ARM_by_an_intern).  Theoretically, Hackintosh on a Chromebook could be done...it just hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @0xDAFACADE I don't think anyone would want to go through the pain that is compiling XNU. I don't think anyone should ever even try because I don't know the uses of Mac OS X on ARM, it would be terrible. Debian would be much easier to use on ARM.

Comment: FYI, my HP Chromebook 14 has an x86_64 processor.